# Horizontal UICollectionView with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I am attempting a horizontal UICollectionView printing out CoreData entries, I get no errors when I enter in data and try to view the data, but the data does not print out in the UICollectionView. It is not an issue with entering the data in CoreData. below is my code to fetch CoreData and print out in UICollectionView, where am I going wrong?

```
class HistoryVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var QBHistory = [QB]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return QBHistory.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "QBCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! QBCollectionViewCell
        do{
            QBHistory = try context.fetch(QB.fetchRequest())
            for each in QBHistory {
                cell.QBName.text = each.qbName
                cell.QBPotential.text = each.qbPotential
                cell.QBValue.text = each.qbValue
                cell.QBBust.text = String(each.qbBust)
                cell.QBRound.text = each.qbRound
            }

        } catch {
            print("oh no it broke")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line in `numberOfItemsInSection`:

```
return QBHistory.count
```

That would be zero, so you have zero cells.

You need to move

```
QBHistory = try context.fetch(QB.fetchRequest())
```

Into `viewDidLoad`, so that it happens *before* your collection view data source query methods are called.